# How to find the mass of a solid, given a variable density function and the solid's bounds?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

My math professor has given me the following problem to prepare for the next test:

Suppose the density of a solid is given by the distance to the $xz$ plane. Find the mass if the solid has a floor defined as the plane $z = y$, walls defined by $y = 0, y = 4 - x^2$, and ceiling defined by the plane $z + y = 14$.

My interpretation of the problem is as follows:

Sketching the solid demostrates that the lower $z$-bound is the plane $z = y$, and the upper $z$-bound is the plane $z = 14 - y$. Sketching the shadow of the solid gives me $y$-bounds of $0$ and $4 - x^2$, which leaves me with $x$-bounds of $-2$ and $2$. The density function is the distance from the $xz$ plane, which is the same as the position along the $y$-axis, and therefore can be represented as $y$. This can be expressed as follows:

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{0}^{4-x^2}\int_{y}^{14-y}ydzdydx$$

However, this nets me an answer of approximately $160.91$, whereas the answer key states that I should get $4032/5$.

Where did I go wrong, and how might I correctly tackle similar problems in the future? Is there something I'm missing in regards to how I solve this kind of problem?